# убрать кнопку добавить в корзину woocommerce когда товара нет в наличии

Tags: woocommerce

Подскажите как убрать кнопку купить (добавить в корзину) у товара со статусом нет в наличие. Вместо этой кнопки будет кнопка Сообщить когда появиться плагин WooCommerce Waitlist.
Если использовать снипет:

```html
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
 function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
  global $product;
  if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
  woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
 }
}
```

кнопка "Сообщить когда появиться" плагина WooCommerce Waitlist тоже пропадает в списке товаров

Comment: Не совсем понятно, куда указанный выше код вставлять ?

Answer (score 1):

Решено.

```html
if (!function_exists('woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart')) {
  function woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;
    woocommerce_get_template('loop/add-to-cart.php');
  }
}

function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item() {
    global $product;
    if ($product->stock_status == 'instock') {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">' . $product->stock . '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="my_quantity">' . '<a class="xoo-wl-btn button btn" data-xoo_product_id ="'.$product->get_id().'" data-min_qty="'.$product->get_min_purchase_quantity().'" style="'.$style.'">'.__($xoo_wl_gl_bntxt_value,'waitlist-woocommerce').'Сообщить когда появиться</a>' . '</div>';

    }
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
```